# Would a collection of entangled particles behave like a superfluid?

Tags: wavefunction, quantum-entanglement, bose-einstein-condensate, coherence, condensation

Superfluidity of a Bose-Einstein condensate comes from the fact that all the particles are found in the same quantum state. They are described by the same macroscopic wavefunction. They never collide because they always travel in the same direction.

A collection of entangled particles is also in the same quantum state. Except the wavefunction is not separable into the product of individual wavefunctions.

Since both entanglement and quantum coherence involve particles being in the same quantum state, would an entangled state shared by many particles lead to superfluidity?

Comment: *"A collection of entangled particles is also in the same quantum state."* No, it isn't. You can't even speak of the states of the individual particles, so to say they are in the same is meaningless.

Comment: You cannot speak of their states until after measurement. If the entangled state is 1/sqrt(2) (|11> + |00>), after measurement the states will be 1 and 1 or 0 and 0.

Comment: And if the entangled state is $1/sqrt(2)(|10\rangle+|01\rangle)$. How does that work with your "same state" idea? And what if you have mixed states? I don't understand how this should work...

Comment: In ultra cold matter the magnetic dipole moments of the involved particles have the chance to align themself. They have this chance because they are no more disturbed from photon interactions with the surrounding matter. From a theoretical point of view it was derived that for low energies the spin of ultra cold particles will get aligned and this is the same as the alignment of the magnetic dipole moments.

Comment: So any group of particles with spin entanglement has the same properties as BEC

Answer (score 1):

Well, the trite answer is "no" because every bit of matter we see around us is in an entangled state. It's the normal classical world.

Comment: May I ask why this was downvoted? is it wrong?